# Euler's proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac x n)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$, but over matrices and complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Euler "proved" that the Taylor series and the binomial expression for $e^x$ are equivalent. The binomial expression for $e^x$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac x n)^n$, and the Taylor series is $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$. His "proof" uses the binomial theorem to expand the binomial expression, and then observes that the terms $n^{-k}{n \choose k}x^k$ approach $\frac{1}{k!}x^k$ for all $k$. He then concludes.

The [Monotone Convergence Theorem for sequences of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_series) can be used to justify this argument in the event that $x$ is non-negative.

[Wikipedia shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2) how to generalise this to negative values of $x$ using the ad-hoc observation that $\left(1 - \frac r n \right)^n  \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n = \left(1-\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)^n$.

What about complex values of $x$? Would it reduce to another ad-hoc observation that both functions satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$? What about matrix values of $x$?

I'd like an argument that still broadly resembles Euler's proof: The term $n^{-k}{n \choose k}x^k$ approaches $\frac{1}{k!}x^k$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Historically speaking you have it backwards.  The limit was the original definition, per Bernoulli.  The number e originated in Bernoullis study of compound interest, as the number of terms in compound interest over a time period increases infinitely.  You should in fact start with this equality and derive everything else from there. Eulers contribution was more in terms of e's properties in calculus.

Comment: @SquishyRhode You're saying you'd start with the compound interest definition and then use Taylor's theorem

Comment: Id start with compound interest definition and prove a variety of other properties, limits, etc.  Id walk it through derivative and eventually to the taylor series.  Ive in fact done this for an introductory calculus course back in junior college.

Comment: But Euler started with Bernoulli's definition, and *then* "expanded out" the binomial to get the Taylor series. So it is the same way round as you said it. It appears to rely critically on monotone convergence

Comment: Yes, he may very well have. And it might be valid too. But back in those days their methods lacked the rigor we appreciate today. Keep that in mind.  Im only pointing out that Bernoullis compound interest definition for e predates any other and is a perfectly valid starting point.

Answer (score 1):

We'll use the triangle inequality.

Pick any element $z$ of any unital Banach algebra $A$. $z$ could be a matrix or a complex number, for instance.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

We can pick a value of $s$ such that the *suffix* of the Taylor series has magnitude at most $\epsilon/3$. In other words, we have that $\sum_{k=s+1}^\infty \frac{\vert z \vert^k}{k!} \leq \epsilon/3$. This follows from the fact that the Taylor series is convergent in the real case.

We then have that for any exponent $n$ in the binomial: $$\left|\left(1+\frac z n\right)^n - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z ^k}{k!}\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^s \left|n^{-k}{n \choose k}z^k - \frac{z^k}{k!}\right| + \sum_{k=s+1}^\infty n^{-k}{n \choose k}\left|z\right|^k + \sum_{k=s+1}^\infty\frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!}.$$
This is using the triangle inequality and the sub-multiplicative property of algebra norms. (Over complex numbers, the norm, written $|z|$, is multiplicative: $|wz|=|w||z|$, therefore also sub-multiplicative).

We break the right-hand side into its three summands: $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^s \left|n^{-k}{n \choose k}z^k - \frac{z^k}{k!}\right| \tag{1},\\ \sum_{k=s+1}^\infty n^{-k}{n \choose k}\left|z\right|^k \tag{2}, \\\sum_{k=s+1}^\infty\frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!} \tag{3}\end{align}.$$

For (3), we see that $$ \sum_{k=s+1}^\infty\frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!} \leq \epsilon/3,$$ by fiat.

For (2), we see that $$\begin{align}
&n^{-k}{n \choose k}\left|z\right|^k  &= \frac1{k!}(1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)\cdots(1-\frac {k-1} n) \left|z\right|^k &\leq \frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!},\\
\implies &\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n^{-k}{n \choose k}\left|z\right|^k&&\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!}\\
&&&\leq \epsilon/3.\end{align}$$

(1) is eventually less than $\epsilon/3$ for large enough $n$ because $\frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!} = \frac1{k!}(1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)\cdots(1-\frac {k-1} n) \to \frac{\left|z\right|^k}{k!}$.

Overall then, for large enough $n$, we see that the difference is at most $\epsilon$.